# Linear system with variable number of equations and unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra

Please help me to solve this system of linear equations with the augmented matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2^1 & \ldots & 2^{n-2} & 2^{n-1} \\
1 & 2^3 & \ldots & 2^{3(n-2)} & 2^{3(n-1)} \\
1 & 2^5 & \ldots & 2^{5(n-2)} & 2^{5(n-1)} \\
\vdots & \vdots &   & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & 2^{2n-1} & \ldots & 2^{(2n-1)(n-2)} & 2^{(2n-1)(n-1)}
\end{array}\right.
\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
2^{n-1} \\
0 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I tried to lead it to the diagonal form but I failed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint see $\text{Vandermonde's determinant}$